# How can I use React style imports for my own files?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, export

I would like to use this form often used in React or in this example react-redux

```
import redux, { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
```

So I tried the obvious:

I created an export file:

```
const exp = {};
exp.a = 'a-1';
exp.b = 'b-1'; 
export default exp;
```

And a file to import it:

```
import {a, b} from './40-export.js';  // this does not work
// import test from './40-export.js';  // this works
// const {a, b} = test;  // this works
```

Comment: You seem to be mixing up named imports and object destructuring. Instead of exporting an object, use `export const a = 'a-1'`

Answer (score 2):

You need to both have an `export default` and named exports. Make standalone `a` and `b` variables that you export, and that you assign to properties of the default export object.

```
export const a = 'a-1';
export const b = 'b-1'; 
export const exp = { a, b }; // if you want this to be a named export too
export default exp;
```

Comment: ... so I can use this form .... `import defaultExport, { export1 [ , [...] ] } from "module-name";` as I see on MDN ... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import ... I'll give it a try ... works ...

Comment: @user17331023 So the thing to be aware of, is that `import { thing } from 'blah'` is not destructing.

Comment: @evolution ... what do you call it then? "named imports" odd that is uses same syntax though.

Comment: @user17331023 [yes, exactly](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-scripts-and-modules.html#prod-NamedImports). The syntax is similar which is why it trips people up, including myself.

Answer (score 0):

```
export const a = 2
export const b = 3
export default const c = 3
```

Then

```
import c , {a, b} from "your/file"
```

Note the use of `{...}` for named imports and the lack of it for default exports.